How to choose a control group in Interrupted Time Series?
I have a dataframe similar to the following:
library(lubridate)
ukraine <- data.frame(date = ymd(c("2020-01-01",
                                   "2020-06-01",
                                   "2021-01-01",
                                   "2021-06-01",
                                   "2020-01-01",
                                   "2020-06-01",
                                   "2021-01-01",
                                   "2021-06-01",
                                   "2020-01-01",
                                   "2020-06-01",
                                   "2021-01-01",
                                   "2021-06-01")),
                      country = c("ukraine",
                                  "ukraine",
                                  "ukraine",
                                  "ukraine",
                                  "romania",
                                  "romania",
                                  "romania",
                                  "romania",
                                  "belarus",
                                  "belarus",
                                  "belarus",
                                  "belarus"),
                      obs_count = c(6,
                                    9,
                                    15,
                                    26,
                                    2,
                                    4,
                                    5,
                                    7,
                                    7,
                                    10,
                                    16,
                                    28))
ukraine

> ukraine
         date country obs_count
1  2020-01-01 ukraine         6
2  2020-06-01 ukraine         9
3  2021-01-01 ukraine        15
4  2021-06-01 ukraine        26
5  2020-01-01 romania         2
6  2020-06-01 romania         4
7  2021-01-01 romania         5
8  2021-06-01 romania         7
9  2020-01-01 belarus         7
10 2020-06-01 belarus        10
11 2021-01-01 belarus        16
12 2021-06-01 belarus        28

I am conducting an Interrupted Time Series analysis to see whether the trend in obs_count (amount of data submitted by Ukrainian birdwatchers) changes following an intervention that occurs in 2022 (the war). From what I have read, it would be instructive to match Ukraine to a control group (i.e. a similar country) and then plot obs_count before and after the intervention in both Ukraine and the matched country. If the trend in obs_count changes in Ukraine after 2022 but not in the control country, then that would lend further support to the conclusion that obs_count was affected by the war.
However, I am struggling to understand how to choose which control country to match Ukraine to. From what I've read, some people use the package MatchIt for choosing appropriate controls, others use propensity score matching. I can't make much sense of how to use either of these methods for my particular use case.
I have data for each Eastern European country and I think it makes sense to choose one of those, given geopolitical similarities. However, I'm not sure how to choose which Eastern European country. In the example I provide, it seems obvious that Belarus would be a better match than Romania. I'm looking for a more formal way of making this decision besides just choosing whichever country has the most similar regression line when I plot obs_count over time. Any help is greatly appreciated.
